# Vue router only for single url

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to use separate Vue routers for individual urls.

Example: `/account` so then it will be `/account#/profile` etc.

I must however keep the fixed routes. I am only implementing vue router on some pages so converting completely over to vue router is not an option. Also don't reply this is a bad idea because I have seen many sites employing this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a base for each of your router(s):

```
const router = new Router({
  base: '/account',
  routes: [
    ...
  ]
})
```

The description from the docs (https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#base):

> **base**
>   The base URL of the app. For example, if the entire single page application is served under `/app/`, then **base** should use the value `"/app/"`.

If you need to use multiple routers with different static bases, specifying a base for each one might be a way to make them play nicely together.

Comment: Excellent, how would I merge the Routers with separated bases into one?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your issue? do you need to merge them into one?